# Wondering if JDO DataNucleus supports SSL for LDAP?

Tags: ssl, ldap, jdo, datanucleus

Generally, we pass our custom socket factory through properties while initializing ldap context to get ssl connection. Wondering if the same is possible through JDO while obtaining persistence manager factory.